# Firestore Run Functions Locally with Admin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run my Cloud Functions locally using the below guide

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

I'd like to be able to use the Admin SDK in my local functions. I've downloaded JSON admin keys at the [Service Accounts Pane](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) of the Google Cloud Console and it says to add it using

> `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/key.json"`

I generated keys using

- the `PROJECTNAME@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` that has
  **`App Engine default service account`** credentials

NOT

- `firebase-adminsdk-CODE@PROJECTNAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with **`firebase-adminsdk`** credentials

### What I tried

I tried to save it down to a separate folder, and I provided the path as relative to root. And I executed this command in terminal while in my `functions` folder. It didn't give me any response. Just went to the next line in Terminal.

> `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/[user]/Documents/[PROJECT]/Service_Account/file_name.json"`

### Questions:

- **Did I download/use the right JSON credentials?**
- **Is there a certain place I need to save that .json file? Or can it be anywhere n my system?**
- **Does that path need to be from root? Or relative to my functions folder?**
- **Where do I need to execute this command?**
- **Should it provide some sort of response that it worked? How do we know if it does?**

Comment: You haven't done anything yet that would even use the credentials.  And, in fact, you almost certainly don't even need the credentials file.  Cloud Functions code deployed with the Firebase CLI will automatically use the default service account credentials without you having to do anything.  So I wouldn't even bother with all this until you know you need it.  Be sure you read the documentation, and pay special attention to step 3 here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: The `export` command simply adds an environment variable to your current shell. Receiving no response is typical; you can confirm this variable was set by: echo "$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS". What happens when you run `firebase emulators:start` as the guide suggests?

Comment: Some of my functions use the Admin SDK to Validate Tokens before executing other commands https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens. Can I do that locally without a Service Account?

Comment: Your code will automatically use the default service account.  You can't avoid using a service account - that much is always required.  You just don't need to specify the one you want to use when using the Firebase CLI.

Comment: So can I validate tokens and write to my database with the default account? If not.....all my questions are still unanswered. And if I need it in the future, my questions still are unanswered. Thanks for being unhelpful!

Comment: And others who need to use it (which many probably do) the default guide doesn't seem to be detailed enough. This post would be helpful to them as well.